# Read nested list with other attributes in Java streams

Tags: java, list, java-stream, iteration

I have a list of object for example Person in turn have couple of lists with few generic attributes like below

```
List<Address> address1 = List.of("1","2","5","6")    
List<Address> address2 = List.of("3","4")    
List<Email> email1 = List.of("1@abc.com","2@abc.com", "3@abc.com")    
List<Email> email2 = List.of("3@xyz.com", "4@xyz.com")    

Person person1 = new Person("smith",22, address1, email1)    
Person person2 = new Person("Alex",30, address2, email2)    
List<Person> person = List.of(person1, person2)
```

I want to iterate the person list and get the size of the two other nested list size for address and email object. in the above example, address size =6 and email =5 which i would like to return

is it possible to achieve this in java streams in single iteration?

Comment: It is not clear for me, what structure (especially what nesting) you really have, can you provide real sourcecode to create example data please?

Comment: sorry about that. let me provide you the example.

Comment: edited wit example

Comment: You're assigning Lists of strings to `List` types `Address` and `Email`.  Please correct or explain.

Comment: yes its string that are added to address and email objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to achieve this in java streams in single iteration?

If you mean one loop, or similar construct, yes.  If you mean, some O(1) solution, no! Whether it is done imperatively or declaratively, there will be iterations somewhere.  The simplest approach is as follows:

Modified your code so it would compile and added a Person record.

```
record Person(String name, int age, List<String> getAddress, List<String> getEmail ) {}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> address1 = List.of("1","2","5","6");    
                List<String> address2 = List.of("3","4");    
                List<String> email1 = List.of("1@abc.com","2@abc.com", "3@abc.com");    
                List<String> email2 = List.of("3@xyz.com", "4@xyz.com");    

                Person person1 = new Person("smith",22, address1, email1);    
                Person person2 = new Person("Alex",30, address2, email2);    
                List<Person> persons = List.of(person1, person2);
```

One possibility.

```
int emailCount = 0;
int addressCount = 0;
for (Person person : persons) {
    emailCount += person.getEmail().size();
    addressCount += person.getAddress().size();
}
System.out.println(emailCount);
System.out.println(addressCount);
```

prints

```
5
6
```

This could also be done with streams but with more overhead. Imo, the problem is that you need to define a way to separate the sums of emails and address lists.  One way is the use `mapMulti` to put each `list.size` in a wrapper (here I am using Map.Entry) along with a string designation.  Then it is just a matter of collecting the sums in a Map for each designation.

```
Map<String, Integer> results = persons.stream()
          .<Entry<String, Integer>>mapMulti((person, consumer) -> {
                  consumer.accept(Map.entry("EmailCount", person.getEmail.size()));
                  consumer.accept(Map.entry("AddressCount", person.getAddress.size()));
           })
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
                  Collectors.summingInt(Entry::getValue)));

               
results.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
AddressCount=6
EmailCount=5
```

I would still go with the loop solution.